# How can I select similar records from mysql database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, similarity

I have a search form and I would like to select similar items from database based on the searched title.

Now I use `SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title LIKE '%".$_SESSION['search']."%';`

But e.g. someone search for 'Jurassic Park2' or 'Jurasic Park 2' it doesn't give 'Jurassic Park 2'.

How can I select those movies which has some character difference against the searced title?

Comment: some thing like [`full text search`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) :)

Comment: You should try better tools for this problem. Please consider ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [Mysql full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) to get started.
Basically you need to create a fulltext index on the field(s) you want to search, then you can use a query to look up similar values:
`MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])`

Comment: Now I understand where to use `Mysql full text search`. +1 for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Could have a look at using soundex, just note the stated limitations and I am not sure on it's performance on a large data set.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

Answer (score 0):

I tried the full text search:

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE MATCH(title) AGAINST('%".$_SESSION['search']."%' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) > 1 ORDER BY title;
```

I tried to rewrite the 1 to 0.5 or other smaller than 1, but was the same result.
It gives the result if it totally contains the searched title.

Jurassic gives Jurassic World

but Jurasic gives nothing

Comment: Bro, do not use `%` here '`%".$_SESSION['search']."%'` Just value wrapped inside single quotes and try again

Comment: I deleted the `%` but nothing changed.

Comment: Side note: You should probably escape your $_SESSION['search'] as well in your query, depending on what you use to connect with your database: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php